# How do I expose my javascript library for other clients to use?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cdn, vert.x

I'm using Vert.x and Angular and I have a javascript library that I would like to allow other people to leverage in their code client-side code.  How can I enable them to do something like:

```
<script src="cdn.myServer/myLib.js"></script>
```

Basically I want to do the same as google does with ajax.googleapis.com for my js library on my server.

Comment: Afaik, cdn allows users to download scripts faster by accessing physically nearby servers, therefore attempting to reduce latency for certain users. So you probably need to deploy your script on multiple servers. Perhaps Google can help you out. First link I clicked: https://www.scalescale.com/rolling-your-own-cdn-build-a-3-continent-cdn-for-25-in-1-hour/

Comment: I less care about downloading scripts faster and more about exposing the resource.  How can I expose my js library so that other people can use it?

Comment: Just upload it on your FTP and share link?

Comment: If I share the link on my FTP can they use it with the script js tag?

Comment: You can use BOWER or NPM to publish your library. So others can includ it in their apps by bowr/npm install. Another way is putting it in github and serve it as static file with https://rawgit.com/.

Comment: @Grammin Emm, of course. Didn't you ever build any website? It works the same way like giving address to your index.html.

Comment: If you add the script to a public folder on your webserver, they can access it as a static resource. There's nothing more to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BOWER or NPM to publish your library. So others can include it in their apps by bowr/npm install. Another way is putting it in github and serve it as static file with rawgit.com.

Comment: Instead of using BOWER, NPM or github can I just serve it up from my own vert.x resource as a static file and allow users to leverage it that way?

Comment: @Grammin Just write a request that answers with JS file.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from CDN, you can also make [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) or [bower](http://bower.io/) package which can be found by other developers in modules repository.